# Is it better to continue the uncomplete charging session of the laptop battery after waking it up or should you just let it discharge first?

Tags: windows-10, battery, battery-life, charging, maintenance

I am using a new battery on my laptop. My OS is Windows 10 and I've searched for this question for a long time.

Suppose it's the end of the day and you are doing the last things on your computer while it's plugged in. It's not fully charged, would you wait till the battery reaches the max point, or continue the charging after waking it up the next day?

Additional Information: I used to keep my battery level in 20-80% interval, but nowadays I've been informed that it may be better to fully charge it to 100%(not overcharging, I'm using a vbs code to alert me when the full level is reached) and not letting it be lower than 20% when it's discharging. Also to avoid overcharging, I mostly don't take the risk to charge while it is on sleep mode when I know I'm going to be away for some long hours.

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter with Lithium based batteries - what does matter is the charge/discharge cycle, as laptop batteries only have ~200 charge/discharge cycles at 100% before they start losing capacity _(~400 when charging only to 80%)_

Comment: The battery manager is often smarter than the user these days. Don't do anything 'special' with it & it will look after itself.

Comment: If your laptop has Battery Threshold management (charge to 80% and stay plugged in) you should use that.

Comment: +1 JW0914, Tetsujin.

Comment: @JW0914 Hi, thank you for your comment. I think I got your point, so do you recommend charging to 80% at max? I can see theoretically it prolongs the battery life but it didn't do much on my prev battery. did you have good experiences with this rule?

Comment: @AmirNaseri it's personal preference and whether the extra 20% makes a difference for your usage _(a program is required to stop the charging, with some OEMs, like Dell, offering the software on their support page)_. You should be able to find the charge/discharge cycle amount from the OEM/seller/manufacturer. A laptop battery won't stop working @ ~200 - ~400 cycles, it will simply have less capacity to hold a charge _(often ~50% capacity)_. To determine current capacity for a battery, the built-in BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics will show it within the diagnostics GUI.